# How to automatically run a method after view initialize

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, view, autorun

I have a mainscope class which help me with initialization other scopes. It is a stackpane - base to another views.

In this class I have got a public method `initialize()` which initialize new view:

```
public void initialize(){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/gui/scopes/LoadScreen.fxml"));
        GridPane gridPane = null;
        try {
            gridPane = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LoadScreenController loadScreenController = loader.getController();
        loadScreenController.setMainScreenController(this);
        loadScreenController.setClient(client);
        setScreen(gridPane);
    }
```

My next view is a class which has a method `afterinit()` and I want to autorun it after the view initialize. The method afterInit() create two threads, so when I want to call it at the end of initialize() the new view shows when the afterInit() stops or finishes work. In another case when I run this method from initialize() I have problem with correctly stop subthreads, because they run when i close my window. Now, the threads have a loops with conditions value<100, and they increase a value from 0 to loop's condition.. So they should stop when the value reach  100 or when i close the window/view.  How can I do it?

Comment: Why not include it at the end of initialize()?

Comment: The method afterInit() create two threads, so when i want to call it at the end of initialize() the new view shows when the afterInit() stops or finishes work

Comment: That might be worth mentioning in the post

Comment: Ok, I added this info to the post

Comment: @A.Staskiewicz
Wrap your call to the afterInit method in a Platform.runLater() like this `Platform.runLater(this::afterInit);`